# Absolute positioning for dynamically created elements

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to overlay text onto a hyperlinked image which has been dynamically created using the *document.createElement()* function. However, even with an absolute position of *left: 0px* and *top: 0px*, the text keeps appearing below the image, and not at the top, left corner as it should:

```
    //mainDiv is a container to hold all the hyperlinked images
    for (i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++)
    {
        img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = imgArray[i].src;
        img.style.width = imgArray[i].wdth;
        img.style.height = "auto";

        imgLink = document.createElement("a");
        imgLink.href = imgArray[i].url;
        imgLink.appendChild(img);

        imgLabel = document.createElement("p");
        imgLabel.innerHTML = imgArray[i].desc;
        imgLabel.style.position = "absolute";
        imgLabel.style.top = "0px";
        imgLabel.style.left = "0px";

        imgContainer = document.createElement("div");
        imgContainer.style.display = "inline";
        imgContainer.style.position = "relative";

        imgContainer.appendChild(imgLabel);
        imgContainer.appendChild(imgLink);
        mainDiv.appendChild(imgContainer);
    }
```

The only problem is the positioning of the text div, *imgLabel*.

***Here's a simplified example of the issue on jsFiddle:*** http://jsfiddle.net/mPL3q/1/

***block & inline-block does not work:*** http://jsfiddle.net/MwjXV/

Comment: what do you mean by `overlaid text`? can you add more details? or create a fiddle?

Comment: try to show us your example in a fiddle please

Comment: To display some text over the image.

Comment: use jsfiddle.net and put ALL your code there. there can be several reasons why this is happening.

Comment: Try This: http://jsfiddle.net/mPL3q/6/

Comment: Why did you set the div to display inline? Is this needed?

Comment: Inline because the images are to be displayed side by side.

Comment: Does inline-block not work for you?

Comment: this page finally helped me see that the problem I had was trying to do `element.style.top = "100";` Instead it had to be "100px" . ‍♂️

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1st solution

```
// label
imgLabel.style.position = "absolute";
imgLabel.style.top = "0px";
imgLabel.style.left = "0px";
imgLabel.style.margin = '0px';

// container    
imgContainer.style.position = "relative";
// tip: parent element of another element containing floated elements 
//      should have property overflow set to hidden
imgContainer.style.float = "left";
imgContainer.style.margin = "5px";
```

2nd solution

```
// label
imgLabel.style.position = "absolute";
imgLabel.style.top = "0px";
imgLabel.style.left = "0px";
imgLabel.style.margin = "0px";

// container        
imgContainer.style.display = "inline-block";
imgContainer.style.position = "relative";
// you will have gaps between the containers even if the margin is set to 0
imgContainer.style.margin = "0px";
// if you don't want these gaps, set margin-left to -5px (but not to the first element)
if(i !== 0){
    imgContainer.style.marginLeft = "-5px";
}
```

`EDIT` After analyzing your code...

```
// change <p> to <label>
imgLabel = document.createElement("label");
imgLabel.innerHTML = "Image " + i;
imgLabel.style.left = "0px";
// you don't need the next line ;)
//imgLabel.style.top = "0px";
imgLabel.style.color = "White";
imgLabel.style.position = "absolute";
```

[1st jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mPL3q/12/) | [2nd jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mPL3q/15/) | [3rd jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MwjXV/2/)

Comment: The container element is set to *position: relative* and the label element is set to *position: absolute* with 0 margins. However, if the container element is not displayed inline, the hyperlinked images will appear vertically, and not side by side.

Comment: @iSofia I added another solution, so choose :)

Comment: The best solution is clearly *display: inline-block*; thank you hex494D49, for your tireless help. However, it does not seem to work in my implementation, where all metrics are based on percentages. I've added a little more detail to my example; it's supposed to be an image scroller, where the images are added dynamically, and their sizes are not known beforehand. ***new jsFiddle:*** http://jsfiddle.net/MwjXV/

Comment: @iSofia I see. I'll fix it in a meantime and drop you a message.

Comment: That would be great; thank you hex494D49. I believe that it has to do with the percentage sizes being inherited from the parent divs, and the parent divs not having any fixed sizing during dynamic creation with *document.createElement()*. That's probably why the div collapses when set to *display: inline-block*. But I just can't seem to structure it right.

Comment: @iSofia Check the updated answer and follow the 3rd jFiddle. I believe it's what you're looking for... and let me know if it is :)

Comment: Wow! *Label* seems to work as expected. Would you happen to know why the *top* attribute isn't quite proportionate? Even setting it to 1px pushes it all the way to the bottom. And again, thank you.

Comment: @iSofia Oh, I see the answer isn't yes accepted hahaha. Well, honestly I'm not sure why the top property shouldn't be used in this case - since the whole web is a mystery sometimes I just follow the instincts. But I'll check it out in the meantime and let you know :)

Comment: Oversight on my part; it's done now, with gratitude I might add. I'll try and look into the *label* mystery as well, but would still love to hear from you if you find anything out. Thanks a whole lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, add

```
img.style.zIndex="1";
```

and

```
imgLink.style.display = "block";
```

to their respective blocks

http://jsfiddle.net/mPL3q/8/

OR

if `inline-block` works for you then

```
imgContainer.style.display = "inline-block";
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mPL3q/7/

Comment: For some reason, using *block* or *inline-block* for the link element or the container element prevents the images from being displayed side by side.

Comment: You are going to have to post more of your code then

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mPL3q/13/ I see them in one line as long as the width of the frame is large enough to fit them. Are you not seeing it?

Comment: Yes, you're right; thank you. Unfortunately, it does not seem to work the same when the metrics are percentage-based. I've posted an expanded example. The images are added dynamically and their sizes are not known beforehand. ***new jsFiddle:*** http://jsfiddle.net/MwjXV/